# Simplex noise displaying incorrectly with BufferedImage

Tags: scala, 2d, bufferedimage, procedural-generation, simplex-noise

I finally got a working tile-able version of Simplex noise working after much work, but I can't seem to get it to record and display correctly when using a BufferedImage. Whenever I try to create an image, it ends up with bands or rings of black and white, instead of a smooth change of shades, which is what I'm expecting. I'm guessing there's something simple I'm not doing, but for the life of me, I can't find it.

This is my code (quite a bit of which is from Stefan Gustavson's Simplex noise implementation):

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import javax.imageio.ImageIO
import java.io.File
import scala.util.Random

object ImageTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val image = generate(1024, 1024, 1)
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("heightmap.png"))
  }

  def generate(width: Int, height: Int, octaves: Int) = {
    val map = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY)
    val pi2 = Math.PI * 2

    for ( x <- 0 until width;
          y <- 0 until height) {
      var total = 0.0

      for (oct <- 1 to octaves) {
        val scale = (1 - 1/Math.pow(2, oct))
        val s = x / width.toDouble
        val t = y / height.toDouble
        val dx = 1-scale
        val dy = 1-scale

        val nx = scale + Math.cos(s*pi2) * dx
        val ny = scale + Math.cos(t*pi2) * dy
        val nz = scale + Math.sin(s*pi2) * dx
        val nw = scale + Math.sin(t*pi2) * dy

        total += (((noise(nx,ny,nz,nw)+1)/2)) * Math.pow(0.5, oct)
      }

      map.setRGB(x,y, (total * 0xffffff).toInt)
    }

    map
  }

  // Simplex 4D noise generator
  // returns -1.0 <-> 1.0
  def noise(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double, w: Double) = {
    // Skew the (x,y,z,w) space to determine which cell of 24 simplices we're in
    val s = (x + y + z + w) * F4; // Factor for 4D skewing
    val i = Math.floor(x+s).toInt
    val j = Math.floor(y+s).toInt
    val k = Math.floor(z+s).toInt
    val l = Math.floor(w+s).toInt
    val t = (i+j+k+l) * G4 // Factor for 4D unskewing

    val xBase = x - (i-t) // Unskew the cell space and set the x, y, z, w
    val yBase = y - (j-t) //distances from the cell origin
    val zBase = z - (k-t)
    val wBase = w - (l-t)

    // For the 4D case, the simplex is a 4D shape I won't even try to describe.
    // To find out which of the 24 possible simplices we're in, we need to
    // determine the magnitude ordering of x0, y0, z0 and w0.
    // Six pair-wise comparisons are performed between each possible pair
    // of the four coordinates, and the results are used to rank the numbers.
    var rankx = 0
    var ranky = 0
    var rankz = 0
    var rankw = 0
    if(xBase > yBase) rankx+=1 else ranky+=1
    if(xBase > zBase) rankx+=1 else rankz+=1
    if(xBase > wBase) rankx+=1 else rankw+=1
    if(yBase > zBase) ranky+=1 else rankz+=1
    if(yBase > wBase) ranky+=1 else rankw+=1
    if(zBase > wBase) rankz+=1 else rankw+=1
    // simplex[c] is a 4-vector with the numbers 0, 1, 2 and 3 in some order.
    // Many values of c will never occur, since e.g. x>y>z>w makes x<z, y<w and x<w
    // impossible. Only the 24 indices which have non-zero entries make any sense.
    // We use a thresholding to set the coordinates in turn from the largest magnitude.
    // Rank 3 denotes the largest coordinate.
    val i1 = if (rankx >= 3) 1 else 0
    val j1 = if (ranky >= 3) 1 else 0
    val k1 = if (rankz >= 3) 1 else 0
    val l1 = if (rankw >= 3) 1 else 0
    // Rank 2 denotes the second largest coordinate.
    val i2 = if (rankx >= 2) 1 else 0
    val j2 = if (ranky >= 2) 1 else 0
    val k2 = if (rankz >= 2) 1 else 0
    val l2 = if (rankw >= 2) 1 else 0
    // Rank 1 denotes the second smallest coordinate.
    val i3 = if (rankx >= 1) 1 else 0
    val j3 = if (ranky >= 1) 1 else 0
    val k3 = if (rankz >= 1) 1 else 0
    val l3 = if (rankw >= 1) 1 else 0
    // The fifth corner has all coordinate offsets = 1, so no need to compute that.

    val xList = Array(xBase, xBase-i1+G4, xBase-i2+2*G4, xBase-i3+3*G4, xBase-1+4*G4)
    val yList = Array(yBase, yBase-j1+G4, yBase-j2+2*G4, yBase-j3+3*G4, yBase-1+4*G4)
    val zList = Array(zBase, zBase-k1+G4, zBase-k2+2*G4, zBase-k3+3*G4, zBase-1+4*G4)
    val wList = Array(wBase, wBase-l1+G4, wBase-l2+2*G4, wBase-l3+3*G4, wBase-1+4*G4)
    // Work out the hashed gradient indices of the five simplex corners
    val ii = if (i < 0) 256 + (i % 255) else i % 255
    val jj = if (j < 0) 256 + (j % 255) else j % 255
    val kk = if (k < 0) 256 + (k % 255) else k % 255
    val ll = if (l < 0) 256 + (l % 255) else l % 255
    val gradIndices = Array(
      perm(ii+perm(jj+perm(kk+perm(ll)))) % 32,
      perm(ii+i1+perm(jj+j1+perm(kk+k1+perm(ll+l1)))) % 32,
      perm(ii+i2+perm(jj+j2+perm(kk+k2+perm(ll+l2)))) % 32,
      perm(ii+i3+perm(jj+j3+perm(kk+k3+perm(ll+l3)))) % 32,
      perm(ii+1+perm(jj+1+perm(kk+1+perm(ll+1)))) % 32)
    // Calculate the contribution from the five corners
    var total = 0.0
    for (dim <- 0 until 5) {
      val (x,y,z,w) = (xList(dim), yList(dim), zList(dim), wList(dim))
      var t = 0.5 - x*x - y*y - z*z - w*w
      total += {
        if (t < 0) 0.0
        else {
          t *= t
          val g = grad4(gradIndices(dim))
          t * t * ((g.x*x)+(g.y*y)+(g.z*z)+(g.w*w))
        }
      }
    }

    // Sum up and scale the result to cover the range [-1,1]
    27.0 * total
  }

  case class Grad(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double, w: Double = 0.0)
  private lazy val grad4 = Array(
    Grad(0,1,1,1), Grad(0,1,1,-1), Grad(0,1,-1,1), Grad(0,1,-1,-1),
    Grad(0,-1,1,1),Grad(0,-1,1,-1),Grad(0,-1,-1,1),Grad(0,-1,-1,-1),
    Grad(1,0,1,1), Grad(1,0,1,-1), Grad(1,0,-1,1), Grad(1,0,-1,-1),
    Grad(-1,0,1,1),Grad(-1,0,1,-1),Grad(-1,0,-1,1),Grad(-1,0,-1,-1),
    Grad(1,1,0,1), Grad(1,1,0,-1), Grad(1,-1,0,1), Grad(1,-1,0,-1),
    Grad(-1,1,0,1),Grad(-1,1,0,-1),Grad(-1,-1,0,1),Grad(-1,-1,0,-1),
    Grad(1,1,1,0), Grad(1,1,-1,0), Grad(1,-1,1,0), Grad(1,-1,-1,0),
    Grad(-1,1,1,0),Grad(-1,1,-1,0),Grad(-1,-1,1,0),Grad(-1,-1,-1,0))

  private lazy val perm = new Array[Short](512)
  for(i <- 0 until perm.length)
    perm(i) = Random.nextInt(256).toShort

  private lazy val F4 = (Math.sqrt(5.0) - 1.0) / 4.0
  private lazy val G4 = (5.0 - Math.sqrt(5.0)) / 20.0
}
```

I've checked the output values of the noise function I'm using, which as of yet hasn't returned anything outside of (-1, 1) exclusive. And for a single octave, the value I'm supplying to the image (`total`) has not gone outside of (0,1) exclusive, either.

The only thing I can see that would be a problem is either the BufferedImage type is set incorrectly, or I'm multiplying `total` by the wrong hex value when setting the values in the image.

I've looked through the Javadocs on BufferedImage for information about the types and the values they accept, though nothing I've found seems to be out of place in my code (though, I am fairly new to using BufferedImage in general). And I've tried changing the hex value, but neither seems to change anything. The only thing I've found that has any affect is if I divide the `(total * 0xffffff).toInt` value by 256, which seems to darken the bands a bit and a slight gradient appears over the areas it should, but if I increase the division too much, the image just becomes black. So as of right now I'm stuck on what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(total * 0xffffff).toInt` doesn't seem to make sense. You are creating an ARGB value from a grayscale float with a single multiplication?

I think you want something like this:

```
  val i   = (total * 0xFF).toInt
  val rgb = 0xFF000000 | (i << 16) | (i << 8) | i
```

That gives me a smooth random texture, although with very low contrast—with 1 octave, your total seems to vary approx from 0.2 to 0.3, so you may need to adjust the scale a bit.

---

I'm not sure though how you can get 16-bit grayscale resolution. Perhaps you need to set the raster data directly instead of using `setRGB` (which forces you down to 8 bits). [The comments below this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116858/write-to-16-bit-bufferedimage-type-ushort-gray) suggest that you use the raster directly.

Comment: I knew it would end up being something simple like this. I guess I missunderstood setRGB when I was looking through the javadocs.